# Symfony2 createFormBuilder and Flashbag issue

Tags: php, forms, symfony, flash-message

i´m using a single action to Display and submit a form built with createFormBuilder

```
public function fooBar(){

    // ... creating form and stuff


    // on first Request i want to use the FlashBag to hold a "Fill out !" message

    // how to if here ? if(first request){
       $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice', "Fill out!");
    // }
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $fooService->create($bar);
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->clear('notice');
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice', "Succesfully Submitted !");
    } else {
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice', "Form is Invalid!");
    }


    // otherwise i see "Fill Out!" and "Form is Invalid" on the First request when i did not fill out anything yet

}
```

i hope my problem is understandable,

essentially its that isValid() evaluates to false if no form was submitted and also evaluates to false if the submitted form contained invalid propertys

and i want to display a specific flasmessage on the first time the form is displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `Request` method for this purpose.

```
// ... creating form and stuff
$request = $this->get('request');

// on first Request i want to use the FlashBag to hold a "Fill out !" message
if ($request->isMethod('GET')) 
{
    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice', "Fill out!");
}
```

Comment: yeah its working, but i think i just found sth. better ->      if($form->isSubmitted()){

Comment: That works for your last question, but your first question was 'on first Request i want to use the FlashBag'. For that case the best way to determine is via the request method check.

Comment: you´re right, its perfectly matching! i didnt know, symfony form is always using POST

Comment: Yes, if form `method` is omitted, the `POST` is set as default in `Symfony`.